# svn on mac - global-ignore directories

Tags: macos, svn, directory, ignore

Running svn version 1.6.17 on mac os x 10.6.8, command line - I have cache directories that I want svn to ignore.

Every time I access the cackephp site, it creates cache .jpg and other files up to five levels deep, inside several 'cache' and 'cached' folders. I need svn to ignore these folders and everything inside them, so using svn propset on each directory is not an option.

To solve this, I edit the file ~/.subversion/config, and under global-ignores I added cache, cache*, cached*, cache/, cached/, but none of these worked.  I tested that adding wildcard filenames to this item works, but I need to ignore directories recursively and not files.

The [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) only explains using single directory-specific svn propset, and wildcard filenames in the global-ignores setting. Any ideas?

Comment: Are these directories already versioned?

Comment: yes. and no... The directories are versioned, but every debug session cake adds many new subdirectories and files in them - and these new files are not versioned.  I'm trying to get SVN to ignore these directories and anything inside them.